# Сортировка выбором, не могу вернуть массив в конце

Tags: c++

cout и cin нет, т.к. пишу под программу, подставляющие тестовые случаи. Выдает такую ошибку:

```
__tester__.cpp: In function ‘int* SelectionSort(int*, int)’:
__tester__.cpp:21:15: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
 return &array[i];
```

Пробовал убирать &, показало invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’.

Вот код:

```cpp
int* SelectionSort(int array[], int size) {
    int min = 0; 
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        min = i; 
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            min = ( array[j] < array[min] ) ? j : min;
        if (i != min)
        {
            max = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min];
            array[min] = max;
        }
    }
    return &array[i];
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Функция возвращает (и принимает кстати тоже) не массив, а указатель. А область видимости переменной `i` ограничена циклом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что вы планируете вернуть из функции **массив** или **максимальный/минимальный** элемент? Потому что по приведенному коду это не очень понятно.

---

Если собираетесь возвращать **массив**, то нужно написать просто `return array`. *(Что кстати не имеет смысла, т.к. новый массив вы в функции не создаете, а изменяете существующий)*. Смотрите более подробно [передача массива в функцию](https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/4.7.php).

---

Если же собираетесь вернуть, **конкретный элемент массива** *(например, максимальный или минимальный)*, то следует изменить тип возвращаемого значения функции на `int SelectionSort(int array[], int size)` и возвращать либо `return array[min]`, либо `return array[max]`.

---

Также следует более внимательней читать описания ошибок, которые предоставляет компилятор, ваша же говорит о том, что переменная `i`, недоступна в текущей области видимости, так как она существует только внутри цикла `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`.

Comment: извиняюсь, забыл написать само условие задания. "Напишите функцию, которая сортирует по возрастанию массив целых чисел методом выбора и возвращает отсортированный массив." (неважно, через return array уже заработало, благодарю вас)

Comment: @SomaSwap ну тогда просто напишите `return array`, вместо `return &array[i]`. Массивы передаются в функцию как указатель на первый элемент, то есть по сути уже являются указателем.